# Deploying nodejs project on nginx server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nginx, nginx-location

I have searched the whole internet and can't find any answer to this.
I've just started my own nginx server and are deploying a nodejs project where I'm using angular 4 and expressjs. It works fine when I use the location '/' in nginx but when i change to '/dbproject' it does'nt work.

First it did'nt found the .js files in my public folder but when I  builded angular with ng build --deploy url = /dbproject it found it, but then I get the errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
styles.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vendor.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < .
```

The odd thing is that it works all fine when i'm using the location '/' in nginx.

Here's the nginx setup:

```
location /dbproject {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Here's the app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const db = require('./config/db');
const app = express();

const users = require('./routes/users');
db.connect(db.MODE_PRODUCTION, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to MySQL.')
    process.exit(1)
  } else {
    console.log("Connectad");
  }
});

// Port Number
const port = 3000;

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/users', users);

// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Invalid Endpoint');
});


app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

Comment: Could you post your entire nginx site setup please?

Comment: in your config, `/dbproject/index.html` is proxy to `http://localhost:3000/dbproject/index.html`

Comment: How should I fix this?

Comment: What if you use ng build --base-href=/dbproject ?

Comment: Then it can't find the .js files:
index.html:18 GET http://XXXXXXX/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:18 GET http://XXXXXXX/polyfills.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:18 GET http://XXXXXXX/styles.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:18 GET http://XXXXXXX/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.html:18 GET http://XXXXXXX/main.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score -1):

It's solved.

Before:

```
location /dbproject {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

After:

```
location /dbproject {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```